# Aligning icon in input field

Tags: css, icons, alignment

I have a couple of issues. I have opted to use focus and blur for text values in input field over placeholder text as there is a issue in chrome with placeholder text being centered.

I need to position the icon in the input field, center to the input field. And cross browser compliant.

I have tried everything to get the thing centered. It's a sprite I made which works fine, that code is ok. Its the alignment vertically of the image that is the issue,

Could someone help please. The LINK to the fiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/F2cdu/1/

All code is done, apart from the input field displaying the text on page load, but we can fix that. Everything else seems ok.

Comment: Could you please add the image resource in the fiddle?

Comment: The image is in the fiddle. Check the css: here is the image http://sitehelp.com.au/images/cancel-sprite.png

Comment: Image is not showing up in text box. please add the image so that we can see it and fix the issue.

Comment: The link you posted takes me to a page.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you need to position .searchreset span above input?
First, you need to wrap them with extra block (div) and make this div position:relative
Then add position:absolute to your .searchreset and use top,left,right,bottom css properties to position .searchreset